# Do bitwise operations of constexpr result in constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I defined a few constants in a way showed below

```cpp
constexpr int a = 1;
constexpr int b = 2;
```

My question is whether all arithmetic and bitwise operations that only use `a` and `b` will be considered as `constexpr` by the compiler?

For example, I'm wondering whether compiler is guaranteed to calculate the expression for `c` compile time? If not, is there a way to ask for compile time calculations?

```cpp
c = (a + b) & (a | b);
```

Comment: I don't think it's guaranteed, but you can count on the compiler to be able to do it. Test with a simple `static_assert` to see if it's evaluated at compile time.

Comment: A test with a simple `static_assert` will show that compiler can calculate it compile time. Alternative solution would be to have a `constexpr` function that takes two `int` as input parameters and returns the value. Having this, we can always write `c  =  function(a, b)`. Which also makes the compiler to calculate things compile time. The fact is that I may have tons of various expressions and simply don't wan't to have a function for each of them.

Comment: @TruLa: Not every invocation of a `constexpr` function is evaluated at compile time.  It's perfect legal to pass variables which aren't compile-time constants to a constexpr function -- then the evaluation has to be done at runtime.

Comment: I totally agree. My point was simply that `static_assert` will just show a theoretical possibility for compile time calculations. I like your trick with `cvalue` and definitely accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is whether all arithmetic and bitwise operations that only use `a` and `b` will be considered as `constexpr` by the compiler?

Such an expression is usable in `constexpr` context, with a few exceptions (anything that causes undefined or implementation-defined behavior must be avoided, e.g. bitwise right shift on a negative quantity, division by zero, overflow of a signed type).

> For example, I'm wondering whether compiler is guaranteed to calculate the expression for c compile time?

Only if the expression is used in a context where a compile time context is required.

> If not, is there a way to ask for compile time calculations?

That's what the `constexpr` keyword applied to a variable will do.  Assuming that you can't just add the qualifier to `c` itself because it is used as a variable (reassigned later based on runtime data, for example) you can still force the calculation to be `constexpr`:

```
constexpr auto cvalue = (a + b) & (a | b);
c = cvalue;
```